# Split express controller into multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a express js controller file created like this

**Path:** `/controllers/usersController.js`

```
// Register User
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
...
}

// Login User
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
...
}

// Forgot Password
module.exports.forgot_password = function(req, res) {
...
}
```

And I am using require() inside route file like this

**Path:** **/routes/users.js**

```
const usersController = require('../controllers/usersController')
router.post('/users/register', usersController.register)
router.post('/users/login', usersController.login)
router.post('/users/forgot_password', usersController.forgot_password)
```

This is all working fine. But my controller code is getting bigger and I want to split the userController.js into separate files so that I can have something like this

```
/controllers/users/index.js
/controllers/users/register.js
/controllers/users/login.js
/controllers/users/forgot_password.js
```

And `/controllers/users/index.js` needs to be the base controller which includes all these separate files. And I can simply use this `index.js` file into the router.

I am not sure how that is done. I tried doing module.export() method inside each separate js files and imported them inside /users/index.js file, but I am getting this error from router.

```
.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] not working
```

Note: I am not allowed to use es6 import statement :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From whatever information I gathered from the question, you can split up the controller file by setting the module.exports to a required function in each separate file.

For example, for the /controllers/users/register.js

```
module.exports = function(req,res){...}
```

And then inside the /controllers/users/index.js

```
let register = require('./register.js');
router.post('/users/register', register);
```

And continue similarly for each controller function.